# Just call a https URL with PHP (without waiting for response)

Tags: php, url, cron

I already googled and searched for an answer, and found also one, but I still get an error...

I just want to start a cronjob by calling a certain URL but I get this failure message:

```
PHP Warning: fopen(https://my-url.de): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/cronjob/import.php on line 41
```

I tried this one:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

But it is not working... The url triggers a cronjob but this one needs to long to response...

So what would you suggest to call a cronjob in PHP?
I must call the cronjob by URL and I do not need to get a response!

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: what about [curl](http://php.net/curl) ??

Comment: Isn't `ignore_user_abort(true);` and `set_time_limit(0);` curl?

Comment: no, however does fopen fails always ? even if you've submitted another link ?

Comment: Other links are working!

Comment: then try to curl your links .

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [curl](http://php.net/curl) instead of fopen as follows

```
$url = 'https://my-url.de';
$ch = curl_init($url);
// this will prevent printing out the contents , unless you are make echo $content
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```